# Отобразить текст (абзац) с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css

Возможно сделать тоже самое визуально, но более элегантно в плане кода? Отобразить текст (абзац) с помощью CSS: http://cssdesk.com/gumNB

Comment: А что не так с уже имеющимся кодом? Чем он вам не нравится?

Comment: Обратите внимание, что в моем коде ссылки в UL списке.

Мне нужно записать в таком же виде (визуально) абзац текста используя тег p. 

Как на этом сайте примерно: http://www.saforian.com/ , но они оборачивают каждую строку в span + br. Я ищу более изящное решение.

Comment: То есть, в одном теге `p` должны быть все ссылки (разделяться пробелом), но чтобы выглядело так, как в твоем примере?

Или что? Не понимаю задачу. Приведи что ли разметку, какой она должна получиться.

Comment: Попробую пояснить. Есть абзац фиксированной ширины, скажем 300px:

<p>"Скоро  ли?  Скоро  ли?  О, эти несносные улицы, лавки, калачи, фонари, извозчики!"</p>

Мне нужно чтобы он визуально выглядел как в моем примере. Можно сделать тоже самое с помощью тегов span и br, например так:

http://cssdesk.com/4SNKN

Я ищу максимально красивое и универсальное решение данного вопроса. В идеале без дополнительных тегов, подстраивающееся под любую ширину абзаца.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. С помощью псевдоэлементов `:bebore` и `:after`.

Но это не добавит элегантности Вашему коду, а скорее наоборот ...

Для разметки используйте `html`, а для стилизации `css`.

Answer (score 0):

[Можно вот так](http://cssdesk.com/BPkUY):

```
<div class="text-frame">
  <span>Скоро ли? Скоро ли? О, эти несносные улицы, лавки, калачи, фонари, извозчики!</span>
</div>

<style>
.text-frame {
  max-width: 150px;
}
.text-frame > span {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  border: #fff 5px solid;
  outline: #fff 5px solid;
  border-style: solid none;
}
</style>
```

На мой взгляд, это изврат.

Comment: Изврат суть вопроса или решение? Думаю пока красивее получается здесь http://cssdesk.com/4SNKN, как у этих ребят http://www.saforian.com/ . 

Если вы насчет сути - визуальное представление подобного вида попадается достаточно часто если не в вебе, то в современном глянце, поэтому хочется найти perfect-решение, чтобы не плодить говноверстку.

Comment: Я имею в виду решение: я о ненормальном применении `border` и `outline`. C другой стороны, [можно еще заменить на box-shadow](http://cssdesk.com/QHUuu).

Но с задачей справляется, верно? В разметке нет жестких переносов, текст переносится автоматом.